# PHP session variable not being stored

Tags: php, session

My session variables are not being stored.

I tried lot of things like `var_dump`, `print_r` and my variables are well printed but not stored.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require "header.php";
?>

    <form action="../Views/index.php?page=createSecteur" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="libelle">Libelle : </label>
            <input type="text" name="libelle" class="form-control" id="libelle" required value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['libelle']) ? $_SESSION['libelle'] : "" ?>">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert_secteur" id="insert_secteur">Insert secteur</button>
    </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['insert_secteur'])) {
    $_SESSION['libelle'] = $_POST['libelle'];
}
require "footer.php";
?>
```

UPDATE :
My $_POST['libelle'] gave me an error "undefined index"

Comment: try to replace `isset($_POST['insert_secteur'])` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` instead

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit better? I didn't see any var_dump in there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not stored?"  Not stored _where_?  How are you attempting to "store" them?  How do you know that that are _not_ being "stored"

Comment: @LucasMeine he meant that he try to track his data by `var_dump`

Comment: @Joseph, I got it, I just couldn't understand where he checked for his variables and they were set, but not stored in session somehow.

Comment: What page you code is strored in? Same you post to?

Answer (score 0):

It does work if you remove action url (If you post to same page):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require "header.php";
    ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="libelle">Libelle : </label>
                <input type="text" name="libelle" class="form-control" id="libelle" required value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['libelle']) ? $_SESSION['libelle'] : "" ?>">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert_secteur" id="insert_secteur">Insert secteur</button>
        </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['libelle'])) {
        $_SESSION['libelle'] = $_POST['libelle'];
    }


    echo $_SESSION['libelle'];
    require "footer.php";
?>
```

If you post to other page then post execution must be done on other page.

But if you need to know specific form was sent you can do this:
By saving hidden input with key name

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require "header.php";
    ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="libelle">Libelle : </label>
                <input type="text" name="libelle" class="form-control" id="libelle" required value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['libelle']) ? $_SESSION['libelle'] : "" ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="source" value="createSecteur"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert_secteur" id="insert_secteur">Insert secteur</button>
        </form>

    <?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if (empty($_POST["source"])){$source = null;}else{$source = htmlentities($_POST['source'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");}

        if($source=='createSecteur'){
            if (isset($_POST['libelle'])) {

                $_SESSION['libelle'] = $_POST['libelle'];
            }
        }
    }


    echo $_SESSION['libelle'];
    require "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Nothing changes :/

Comment: Then your `$_POST['libelle']` is empty

Comment: That could be because you maybe post to other page? Or page is the same? If page is the same then make action emty like `action=""`

Comment: @Q.Rey with your exiting code try just with empty action `action=""`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if `$_POST['libelle']` exists too.
Also try to post to the same page by empty the `action` of your form.
This will automatically be the same page when empty.

```
<?php
session_start();
require "header.php";
?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="libelle">Libelle : </label>
            <input type="text" name="libelle" class="form-control" id="libelle" required value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['libelle']) ? $_SESSION['libelle'] : "" ?>">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert_secteur" id="insert_secteur">Insert secteur</button>
    </form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' AND isset($_POST['insert_secteur']) AND isset($_POST['libelle'])) {
    $_SESSION['libelle'] = $_POST['libelle'];
}
require "footer.php";
?>
```